# Questions re: assembly generated from my C++ by gcc

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, x86

Compiling this code:

```
int main ()
{
    return 0;
}
```

using:

> `gcc -S filename.cpp`

...generates this assembly:

```
        .file   "heloworld.cpp"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    .cfi_personality 0x0,__gxx_personality_v0
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    movl    $0, %eax
    popl    %ebp
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

My questions:

1. Is everything after "." a comment?
2. What is .LFB0:?
3. What is .LFE0:?
4. Why is it so big code only for "int main ()" and "return 0;"?

P.S. I read alot of assembly net books, a lot (at least 30) of tutorials and all I can do is copy code and paste it or rewrite it. Now I'm trying a different approach to try to learn it somehow. The problem is I do understand what are movl, pop, etc, but don't understand how to combine these things to make code "flow". I don't know where or how to correctly start writing a program in asm is. I'm still static not dynamic as in C++ but I want to learn assembly.

Comment: You can find some video here that should help you understand assembly language : http://www.securitytube.net/groups?operation=view&groupId=5 The guy has a strong east european accent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As other have said, `.file`, `.text`, ... are assembler directives and `.LFB0`, `.LFE0` are local labels. The only instruction in the generated code are:

```
pushl   %ebp
movl    %esp, %ebp
movl    $0, %eax
popl    %ebp
ret
```

The first two instruction are the function prologue. The frame pointer is stored on the stack and updated. The next intruction store 0 in `eax` register (i386 ABI states that integer return value are returned via the `eax` register). The two last instructions are function epilogue. The frame pointer is restored, and then the function return to its caller via the `ret` instruction.

If you compile your code with `-O3 -fomit-frame-pointer`, the code will be compiled to just two instructions:

```
xorl    %eax,%eax
ret
```

The first set `eax` to 0 (it only takes two bytes to encode, while `movl 0,%eax` take 5 bytes), and the second is the `ret` instruction. The frame pointer manipulation is there to ease debugging (it is possible to get backtrace without it, but it is more difficult).

Comment: gcc -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer heloworld.cpp



/tmp/ccVdrv9G.o:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'

collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: You should use `g++` to compile `.cpp` file. I don't think it is the issue in your case, but it is generally a good idea. I do not have a problem when trying to compile `heloworld.cpp` on my side with `gcc -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer heloworld.cpp` ...

Answer (score 3):

`.file`, `.text`, etc are assembler directives.

`.LFB0`, `.LFE0` are local labels, which are normally used as branch destinations within a function.

As for the size, there are really only a few actual instructions - most of the above listing consists of directives, etc. For future reference you might also want to turn up the optimisation level to remove otherwise redudant instructions, i.e. `gcc -Wall -O3 -S ...`.

Answer (score 2):

It's just that there's a lot going on behind your simple program.

If you intend to read assembler outputs, by no means compile C++. Use plain C, the output is far clearer for a number of reasons.